# Facebook js error - "'Array' is undefined" when calling FB.init

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

About 50% of the time, when calling FB.init, I get this javascript error:

[image]

Refreshing the page sometimes fixes the issue. I can't discern any particular pattern.

Does anyone recognize this code? Is it part of the facebook js sdk?

How do I figure out what is going wrong? I checked the open issues at the Facebook support site but did not see anything.

This is my init code straight out of the fb docs:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        debugger;
        FB.init({
            appId: xxxx,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        debugger;
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: I've never seen this kind of error. The JS code you asked looks like from Facebook. Maybe a conflict with other JS? By the way, your app id number must be quoted.

Comment: The appid was quoted. I just removed it for the post. Thanks. I'll try removing my other js libraries. You might be right.

Comment: I removed all js libraries except for jQuery and still get the problem sporadically.

Comment: I don't know what to do from now on. Those facebook's JS files are very obscure for me... Can you put your URL here to check?

Comment: Sure. I haven't seen the error yet today. Perhaps they fixed it.